# How to add marker on multiple coordinates using ol maps?

Tags: jquery, maps, openlayers

I'm using Ordinance Survey EPSG:27700 leisure layer in OpenLayers map. And I have created the routes successfully. And able to display the routes on the map. But I want to add the markers in all the coordinates I have and also want to make the coordinates draggable and for that, I have looked many examples on the net but unable to add the marker icon on the map. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OS Maps API | Basic Map (EPSG:27700) | OpenLayers</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" />
        <style>
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            form {
                display: block;
            }
            #map { 
                position:absolute; 
                top:0; 
                bottom:0;
                width: 800px;
                height: 500px;
            }
            .span12 {
                width:800px; 
                height: 500px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>   
        <script>
            var apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxetIKMO';

            var base_url = window.location.origin;
            var icon_url = "/img/marker.png";

            var serviceUrl = 'https://osdatahubapi.os.uk/OSMapsAPI/wmts/v1';

            var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
            var map;

            // Setup the EPSG:27700 (British National Grid) projection.
            proj4.defs("EPSG:27700", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.999601 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs");
            ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
            var bng = ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700');
            bng.setExtent([ -238375.0, 0.0, 900000.0, 1376256.0 ]);


            // console.log(ol.proj.fromLongLat(points, 'EPSG:27700'));

            fetch(serviceUrl + '?key=' + apiKey + '&service=WMTS&request=GetCapabilities&version=2.0.0')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(text => {
                    var result = parser.read(text);
                    var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
                        layer: 'Leisure_27700'
                    });

                    var source = new ol.source.WMTS(options);
                    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: source });

                    var viewOptions = {
                        projection: options.projection,
                        resolutions: options.tileGrid.getResolutions(),
                        center: [ 337297, 503695 ],
                        zoom: 7
                    }

                    // Set the default center of the map view.
                    map = new ol.Map({
                        layers: [ layer ],
                        target: 'map',
                        view: new ol.View(viewOptions)
                    });

                    var cord = new Array(['336555.3571805824', '503945.0759345037'], ['336630.3808312133', '504033.339052893'], ['336895.1701863812', '504055.4048324903'], ['337314.41999873036', '503945.0759345037'], ['337250.42923789815', '503808.2681010003']);
                    var points = new Array();
                    cord.forEach(function(element) {
                        points.push([parseFloat(element[0]), parseFloat(element[1])]);
                    });

                    var liniess = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        style: new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#2ECC40'
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#2ECC40',
                                width: 5
                            }),
                            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                radius: 7,
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: '#2ECC40'
                                })
                            })
                        }),
                        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                            features: [new ol.Feature({
                                geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(points)
                            })]
                        }),
                    });

                    map.addLayer(linie);

                    var features = new ol.Collection();
                    var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                            features: features
                        }),
                        style: new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: '#2ECC40'
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#2ECC40',
                                width: 5
                            }),
                            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                                src: icon_url
                            })
                        })
                    });

                    featureOverlay.setMap(map);

                    var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                        features: features,
                        // the SHIFT key must be pressed to delete vertices, so
                        // that new vertices can be drawn at the same position
                        // of existing vertices
                        deleteCondition: function(event) {
                            return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) && ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
                        }
                    });
                    map.addInteraction(modify);

                    var draw; // global so we can remove it later
                    function addInteraction() {
                        draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                            features: features,
                            type: ('LineString'), /** #type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */
                            style: new ol.style.Style({                    
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#2ECC40',
                                    width: 4
                                }),
                                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                    radius: 7,
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: '#2ECC40'
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        });
                        map.addInteraction(draw);
                    }

                    addInteraction();

                    map.on('click', function(event) {
                        var feature = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel)[0];
                        if (feature) {
                            var coordinate = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();               
                        }
                    });
                });       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this example you could style the coordinates of your LineString as a MultiPoint geometry https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html

```
            style: [
              new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#2ECC40'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#2ECC40',
                    width: 5
                })
              }),
              new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    src: icon_url
                }),
                geometry: function(feature) {
                    return new MultiPoint(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                }
              })
            ],
```